# How do I construct a Homeomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}\times \{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise that wants me to construct a concrete example of a homeomorphism
$$
\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}\times\{0,1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
I have no idea where even to begin, I already have trouble finding a bijection, let alone a homeomorphism. Looking up some similar questions led me to the Sierpinski theorem, which states that every countable metric space without isolated points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. However, we haven't had that in our lecture, so I doubt that I'm allowed to use it.

Comment: Hint: if you take the set of rationals less than $\sqrt{2}$, it is homeomorphic to all of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is every countable dense subset of $\mathbb R$ ambiently homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68946/is-every-countable-dense-subset-of-mathbb-r-ambiently-homeomorphic-to-mathb) Or this? [Let $(P,<),(Q,\prec)$ be countable, dense, and linearly ordered sets without endpoints. Then $(P,<),(Q,\prec)$ are order-isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940700)

Comment: @AnneBauval sadly not, as the exercise expects me to provide a concrete homeomorphism, so just saying that it exists by a theorem is not sufficient. Also, I dont know if $\mathbb{Q}\times\{0,1\}$ can be ordered, but maybe it can

Comment: @NielsSlotboom For something explicit, take the lexicographic ordering. Abstractly, any set can be (well) ordered

Comment: Hint: Using the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$, we see that $\mathbb{Q}\times\{0,1\}$ is disconnected.  Is $\mathbb{Q}$ disconnected? (yes)  Can you write $\mathbb{Q}$ as a union of two open sets?  Then, connect this idea to @CheerfulParsnip 's approach.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2934181): $\Bbb Q\simeq\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}.$